# Do I understand the meaning of "take ownership" correctly in QT?

Tags: qt

"Any existing proxy model will be removed, but not deleted. The file dialog will take ownership of the proxyModel."

This is from QT (5.4.0) document regarding the following method

```
QFileDialog::​setProxyModel(QAbstractProxyModel * proxyModel)
```

Here, "take ownership of the proxyModel", my understanding is that I don't need to delete the proxyModel, QFileDialog instance will delete it instead. Am I right?

After my testing I find that QFileDialog instance will not delete proxyModel if it is not the parent of proxyModel. So, I'm a little confused by the document. Maybe this is an error in the document, but I'm not sure.

Comment: In Qt, if an object "owns" another object it's responsible for deleting it. See this page for all the details: http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/objecttrees.html

Comment: If the model isn't deleted, that sounds like a Qt bug.

Answer (score 3):

The root cause has been found, i.e. setProxyModel only works when QFileDialog::DontUseNativeDialog is set.